# how to call an Attachment in a test class

Tags: unit-test, controller

Can any one help me out.I have a controller and their is a test class written ,but the code coverage is low.How to call an Attachment in a test class.Any help very much appreciated.

Controller :

```
    public with sharing class CaseCommentAndEmailPageController {
        String caseId;
        public List<CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper> caseCommentAndEmailWrapperList{get; set;}
        //public String sessionId{get; set;}
        public String emailMessageId{get; set;}
        public String caseCommentId{get; set;}
        public Case cas{get; set;}
        ApexPages.StandardController controller;
        public Boolean isShowList{get; set;}
        public Boolean isButtonVisible{get; set;}
        public Integer recCount{get; set;}
        public List<CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper> newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList{get; set;}
        public Integer totalCount{get; set;}
 public CaseCommentAndEmailPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            this.controller=controller;
            isButtonVisible= true;
            recCount=5;
            init();
            }
        private void init(){
newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList = newList<CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper>();
      caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
   StringshowList=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('showList');
            if(caseId != null){
 cas = [Select Id,contactId,Email_to_Case_Address__c,Status,Email_CC_Address__c,Email_BCC_Address__c,Subject,CaseNumber From Case where id =: caseId];
                if(cas.status == 'New' || cas.status == 'Assigned'){
                    isButtonVisible= false;
                }
                caseCommentAndEmailWrapperList = new List<CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper>();
                if(caseId != null){
                    List<Case_Comment__c> caseCommentList;
caseCommentList = [Select Id,Comments__c,Action_Name__c,Case_Number__c,Assigned_To_CSR__c,createdDate,CreatedById,CreatedBy.Name,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedBy.Name,
                                          (Select Id from Attachments) From Case_Comment__c where Case_Number__c =: caseId Limit 1000];
     for(Case_Comment__c caseComment : caseCommentList){
     List<Attachment> caseAttachmentList = caseComment.attachments;
     if(caseAttachmentList  != null && caseAttachmentList .size() > 0){ CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper caseCommentWrapper = new CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper(caseComment,null,null,true,caseComment.createdDate,true,'Customer Comment');
                            newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.add(caseCommentWrapper);
                        }
                        else{
                            CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper caseCommentWrapper = new CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper(caseComment,null,null,true,caseComment.createdDate,false,'Customer Comment');
                            newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.add(caseCommentWrapper);
                        }
                    }

                    List<Internal_Case_Comment__c> internalCaseCommentList;
                                                   internalCaseCommentList = [Select Id,Comment__c,Action_Name__c,Case__c,Assigned_To_CSR__c,createdDate,CreatedById,CreatedBy.Name,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedBy.Name,
                                                                             (Select Id from Attachments) From Internal_Case_Comment__c where Case__c =: caseId Limit 1000];


                    for(Internal_Case_Comment__c internalCaseComment : internalCaseCommentList ){
                        List<Attachment> caseAttachmentList = internalCaseComment.attachments;
                        if(caseAttachmentList  != null && caseAttachmentList .size() > 0){
                            CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper caseCommentWrapper = new CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper(null,internalCaseComment ,null,true,internalCaseComment.createdDate,TRUE,'Internal Comment');
                            newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.add(caseCommentWrapper);
                        }
                        else{
                            CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper caseCommentWrapper = new CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper(null,internalCaseComment ,null,true,internalCaseComment.createdDate,false,'Internal Comment');
                            newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.add(caseCommentWrapper);
                        }
                    }

                    List<EmailMessage> emailMessageList;

                        emailMessageList = [Select Id,Subject,ParentId,HasAttachment,ActivityId,BccAddress,CcAddress,FromAddress,FromName,HtmlBody,MessageDate,TextBody,ToAddress,createdDate,CreatedById,CreatedBy.Name,
                                                           LastModifiedById,LastModifiedBy.Name,Status
                                                           From EmailMessage where parentId =: caseId Limit 1000];


                    for(EmailMessage emailMessage : emailMessageList){
                        CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper caseCommentWrapper ;
                        if(emailMessage.HasAttachment){
                            caseCommentWrapper = new CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper(null,null,emailMessage,false,emailMessage.MessageDate,true,'Email');
                        }
                        else{               
                            caseCommentWrapper = new CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper(null,null,emailMessage,false,emailMessage.MessageDate,false,'Email');
                        }
                        newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.add(caseCommentWrapper);
                    }                  


                    sortList(newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList);  
                    Integer size = newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.size();     



                    if(showList == null || showList != '1'){      

                        if(size > recCount){
                            size = recCount;
                            isShowList = true;

                        }
                        else{
                            isShowList = false;


                    }
                    else{
                        isShowList= false;

                    }
                    for(Integer i = 0; i< size ; i++){
                        caseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.add(newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList[i]);
                    }                     
                }
            }
            totalCount = newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.size();
        }

        //Selection sort to sort List according to date and time
        private void sortList(List<CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper> newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList){
             Integer listSize = newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.size();
             for (Integer i = 0; i < listSize - 1; i++)
             {
                Integer index = i;
                for (Integer j = i + 1; j < listSize; j++)
                    if (newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList[j].createdDate > newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList[index].createdDate) 
                        index = j;

                CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper smallerNumber = newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList[index];  
                newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList[index] = newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList[i];
                newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList[i] = smallerNumber;
            }
        }

        public void deleteEmailMessge(){
            System.debug('Email message Id  = '+ emailMessageId);

            if(emailMessageId != null && emailMessageId != 'null'){
                delete new EmailMessage(id=emailMessageId);
                init();
            }
        }


        public PageReference addComment(){
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/AddInternalCaseCommentPage?cid='+caseId);
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRef;
        }

        public PageReference sendEmail()
            System.debug('Working.....................');
            if(cas.Email_CC_Address__c == null || cas.Email_CC_Address__c == 'null'){
                 System.debug('cas.Email_CC_Address__c = '+cas.Email_CC_Address__c);
                cas.Email_CC_Address__c ='';
            }
            if(cas.Email_BCC_Address__c == null || cas.Email_BCC_Address__c == 'null'){
                System.debug('cas.Email_BCC_Address__c = '+cas.Email_BCC_Address__c);
                cas.Email_BCC_Address__c ='';
            }
            System.debug('cas.CaseNumber = '+cas.CaseNumber);
            System.debug('cas.Subject = '+cas.Subject);
            String subject = cas.CaseNumber+' - '+cas.Subject;
            if(subject.length() >= 100){
                subject = subject.subString(0,99);
                System.debug('Sub cas.Subject = '+subject);
            }
            String redUrl = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid='+cas.contactId+'&p26='+cas.Email_to_Case_Address__c +'&rtype=003&p3_lkid=' +cas.id +
                             '&p4='+cas.Email_CC_Address__c+'&p5=' + cas.Email_BCC_Address__c + '&p6='+subject+     
                            '&retURL=/'+ cas.id ;
            System.debug('redUrl = '+redUrl );
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor');
             System.debug('End.....................');
             pageRef.getParameters().put('p2_lkid',cas.contactId);
             pageRef.getParameters().put('p26',cas.Email_to_Case_Address__c);
             pageRef.getParameters().put('rtype','003');
             String caseId = cas.id;
             if(caseId != null && caseId.length() > 15){
                 pageRef.getParameters().put('p3_lkid',caseId.subString(0,15));
             }
             pageRef.getParameters().put('p4',cas.Email_CC_Address__c);
             pageRef.getParameters().put('p5',cas.Email_BCC_Address__c);
             pageRef.getParameters().put('p6',subject);
             pageRef.getParameters().put('retURL',cas.id);
           // pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRef;
        }

        public void showMore(){
            recCount +=5;
            refreshList();
        }

        private void refreshList(){
             if(recCount > totalCount){
                 recCount = totalCount;
             }
             caseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.clear();
             for(Integer i = 0; i< recCount ; i++){
                 caseCommentAndEmailWrapperList.add(newCaseCommentAndEmailWrapperList[i]);
             }

        }

        public class CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper{
            public Case_Comment__c caseComment{get; set;}
            public Internal_Case_Comment__c internalCaseComment{get; set;}
            public EmailMessage emailMessage{get; set;}
            public Boolean isCaseComment{get; set;}


            public DateTime createdDate{get; set;}
            public Boolean isAttached{get; set;}
            public String Type{get; set;}
            public String dateString{get; set;}

            public CaseCommentAndEmailWrapper(Case_Comment__c caseComment,Internal_Case_Comment__c internalCaseComment,EmailMessage emailMessage,Boolean isCaseComment,DateTime createdDate,Boolean isAttached,String type){            
                this.caseComment = caseComment;
                this.emailMessage = emailMessage;
                this.isCaseComment = isCaseComment;

                Timezone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();


                dateString = createdDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss',tz+'');
                String[] splitDAte=dateString.Split(' ');
                String timeString = splitDAte[1];
                String[] splitTime = timeString.split(':');
                Integer hourValue = Integer.valueOf(splitTime[0]);
                if(hourValue  > 12){
                    //dateString = createdDate.month()+ '/'+createdDate.day()+'/'+createdDate.year()+' '+(createdDate.hour() - 12)+':'+strminute+' PM';
                    dateString = splitDAte[0]+' '+(hourValue - 12)+':'+splitTime[1]+' PM';
                }
                else{
                    if(hourValue  == 12){
                         dateString = splitDAte[0]+' '+ hourValue +':'+splitTime[1]+' PM';
                    }
                    else{
                        dateString = splitDAte[0]+' '+ hourValue +':'+splitTime[1]+' AM';
                    }
                }
                this.createdDate = createdDate;


                this.isAttached = isAttached;
                this.internalCaseComment = internalCaseComment;
                this.type = type;
            }
        }
    }
```

Test class

```
@isTest
public class CaseCommentAndEmailPageControllerTest{
public static TestMethod void TestCaseCommentAndEmailPageController(){
Account acc =TestDataGenerator.createAccount('edbAccount','Commercial','Basic');
        insert acc;

        Contact con = TestDataGenerator.createContact('joyTest',acc,'joyTest@gmail.com');
        insert con;

        Case cs = TestDataGenerator.createCase(con,'Reopened');
        cs.Email_CC_Address__c = 'test@gmail.com';   
        cs.Email_BCC_Address__c = 'test1@gmail.com';
        cs.Email_to_Case_Address__c = 'support@techie.com';
        insert cs;

Case_Comment__c customCaseComment = TestDataGenerator.createCustomCaseComment(cs,'Reopened');
        insert customCaseComment;
        EmailMessage emailMsg = TestDataGenerator.createEmailMessage(cs);
        emailMsg.fromAddress = 'support@techie.com';
        emailMsg.subject = cs.caseNumber +' - '+cs.Subject;
        emailMsg.parentId = cs.id;
        insert emailMsg;
        Test.startTest();
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().put('id',cs.id);
        ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(cs);
        CaseCommentAndEmailPageController caseCommentEmail = new CaseCommentAndEmailPageController(controller);

        caseCommentEmail.emailMessageId = emailMsg.id;
        caseCommentEmail.deleteEmailMessge();
        caseCommentEmail.addComment();
        caseCommentEmail.sendEmail();
        caseCommentEmail.showMore();

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call an attachment"? Are you creating an attachment in your test class? If not how do you expect your code to find one that does not exist?

Comment: Helpful SFSE forum etiquette tip -- please format your code cleanly - especially the indenting which makes it very hard to read. Eliminate lines that are not relevant to the problem at hand

Comment: @Eric,@crop1645:Thanks for your response.How to add an attachment in a test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is how to add attachments in a test, code like this will do the job:

```
Case_Comment__c c = ...;

insert c;

Attachment a0 = new Attachment(ParentId = c.Id, Name = 'n0', Body = Blob.valueOf('b0'));
Attachment a1 = new Attachment(ParentId = c.Id, Name = 'n1', Body = Blob.valueOf('b1'));
insert new Attachment[] {a0, a1};
```